# Logging all TCP connections to kubelet. How?

Tags: logging, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, firewall

I'd like to see all connections made to kubelet VM.

---

I have a Service Type=NodePort installed in GKE cluster, and this particular node port exposed in my firewall. The service is working perfectly fine. Now, I want to gather logs about TCP connections made to the service. In particular, I'm interested in auditing IPs of clients who connect to it.

According to "[Firewall Rules Logging overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewall-rules-logging)", I've enabled the logging using gcloud:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules update my-firewall-rule --enable-logging
```

After forcing a TCP connection to the port and fetching the logs (via command below), I don't see any TCP connections listed – I only see two logged operations, both related to me running `gcloud` command above:

```
gcloud logging read 'resource.type="gce_firewall_rule"' --format=json
```

**Am I missing anything?**

**Update**. Some further details:

- "GCE Subnetwork" in "**Logging > Logs ingestion**" is enabled
- Looking under VM logs doesn't reveal any logs either:

  ```
  gcloud logging read 'resource.type="gce_instance" resource.labels.instance_id="0000000000000000000"' --format=json
  ```

  (all zeros is not a real ID here)
- I am **not** using a legacy network

Comment: You should see the logs created under the VM resource in logging, not the firewall rule

Comment: @PatrickW thanks, I tried that. Still nothing :|

Comment: do you have Insufficient permissions, or if the subnet may be excluded from Stackdriver another thing id this is " Legacy networks" then it will not work

Comment: It seems you want to see the logs for the firewall. So can you try the "gce_subnetwork" as the resource type  

`gcloud beta logging read 'resource.type="gce_subnetwork" `

Comment: @Jason precisely. I arrived at a different query yesterday which solved my problem, but I will gladly accept your answer if you post as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to see the logs for the firewall. So you can use the "gce_subnetwork" as the resource type:

$gcloud beta logging read 'resource.type="gce_subnetwork"